# Unlock a domain for transfer when it it registered through domains by proxy

Tags: domains, dns

I  registered a domain using Google apps. The process was simple and only cost $10 and the domain was registered automatically by Google through Godaddy.

Now I need to transfer the domain to its new owner and the new owner's tech support team are having difficulty getting it transferred over. They have asked me to do the following:

1. Unlock the domain for transfer
2. Remove the private registration
3. Provide a transfer code

The private registration is through domains by proxy. is there some way to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [FAQ](https://www.domainsbyproxy.com/FAQ.aspx):

> To transfer a privately registered
>   domain name away from a DBP-affiliated
>   Registrar, you only need to perform
>   two steps:
>
> First, log in to your DBP account and
>   cancel the private registration
>   service for the domain name you want
>   to transfer. Second, log in to your
>   Registrar customer account and unlock
>   the domain name. Once completed, you
>   can then initiate the transfer process
>   at the Registrar of your choosing.